# str.contains() returns the wrong answer regardless of regex flag

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series with dtype object that contains curency strings, like '$ 50000'. Not all of them are in dollars, some for example are 'GBP 43000' etc. I am trying to use Pandas to figure out which contain $ and which don't.

The series is called `valid_usa_gross`. To find out which rows in it contain $, first I tried this

```
valid_usa_gross_USD = valid_usa_gross.str.contains('$')
```

the series it returned had `True` everywhere, so I assumed all rows had $, but I was wrong. By inspecting the CSV file, I found entries with different currencies. I then discovered that, unless I specify `regex=False`, the string I pass to `contains()` will be interpreted as regex, and God knows what $ may mean in that case. So I tried

```
valid_usa_gross_USD = valid_usa_gross.str.contains('$', regex=False)
```

which resulted in a series with `False` everywhere. That is also incorrect, because the vast majority of the entries in `valid_usa_gross_USD` do contain a $ symbol. I even tried to escape the $ or add an 'r' in front of the search string, the result is always wrong (either all `True` or all `False`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: " be interpreted as regex, and God knows what $ may mean in that case" You know you can look that up, right? Anyway, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was the encoding. I was reading the whole CSV as

`imdb_raw = pd.read_csv(dataset_path)`

and that didn't throw any errors, so I had no reason to suspect anything. However, reading it as

`imdb_raw = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, encoding='ISO-8859-1)`

results in the $ correctly displayed.